# How to stop redirection to a primary website when a subdomain website on IIS is stopped?

Tags: redirect, iis, subdomain

I have a primary website setup on IIS 7.5 as example.com. There are 2 subdomains configured as a.example.com and b.example.com. So total I have 3 websites 1 primary and 2 under subdomains setup with host-header redirection.

My question: When I stop 1 of the subdomain websites from IIS (right click the website and stop) and then try to access it from the browser as a.example.com then it redirects to example.com. I want IIS not to redirect it to the primary website and instead throw an error something like - e.g. "Service not available" for a.example.com. How do I achieve this?

All my websites - primary and subdomain websites use wildcard SSL.

Comment: What you're describing will only happen if your `example.com` website is set-up to *also* handle all host-headers (`*`), not just `example.com`. You'll need to create a new website entry that serves the catch-all.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the right direction. The headers for subdomains were SET but for the primary domain the host-header field was BLANK. Added example.com there and it did the job. Thank you!